# convergence of MSE (mean square error) using Sequential monte carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, particle-filter

I am using sequential monte carlo method for a regression problem with bayesian estimation . I am trying to find a measure to confirm that my distribution has converged to the actual posterior distribution of interest. 
I think, mean squared error of prediction variable with the measurement summed over all the measurements and particles can give a good measure. but, how to verify/quantify that the value of MSE that i get is reasonable? Should I run the smc with different priors and compare the convergence of MSE between different runs.

Thanks,